# Как запустить redis/resque на Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, heroku

Добрый день, господа. Вопрос следующий: настроил `resque` на локальном сервере, выполняются как периодические задачи, так и моментальный фоновые. Теперь хочу чтобы то же самое работало на `heroku`. Как заставить `resque` стучаться на `rediscloud` на `heroku` и в `localhost` если на локалке?

Создал **redis.rb**:

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]

  $redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])

else

  $redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)

end
```

Было **resque.rb**:

```
require 'resque-scheduler'

uri = URI.parse("redis://localhost:6379/")

Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)


Resque.rake:

require 'resque/tasks'  
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment  

namespace :resque do
    task :setup do
        require 'resque'     
        Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'
    end

  task :setup_schedule => :setup do
    require 'resque-scheduler'
    require 'resque/scheduler/server'
    # Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true

    RAILS_ROOT = Rails.root
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config/resque_schedule.yml'))
  end

  task :scheduler => :setup_schedule

end
```